# Do please let me know

Tags: grammar, rhetoric

I've been using this sentence for a while now, but someone suggested to me that it doesn't sound like proper English.

"Do please let me know [e.g. if you need more information]" (1)

vs

"Please let me know" (2)

or even

"Please do let me know" (3)

My thinking is that the "do" in (1) and (3) tends to make it sound more genuine than (2) (as suggested in [this related – but not identical– question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79649/do-replacing-please)), while placing "do" before "please", a slightly unexpected order, insists even more on that aspect. But perhaps it's just bad grammar.

Comment: Welcome to the site. This question is essentially a duplicate of the question you refer to, and upon review, I find that the answers there fit here, too. So I'm flagging it as a duplicate.

Comment: Proper english is the spin you put on a ball in billiards. This site is about proper English, a West Germanic language. Billiards is off-topic here.

Comment: Not particularly welcoming to be honest. I'm not a native English speaker, so yes, I make mistakes. Also, I made the effort of searching for similar questions, obviously read the one I linked to, and it's not an exact duplicate: "replacing" is not about changing the order. It's mentioned in the comments, sarcastically as far as I can tell, but that's not very useful.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I don't care... english or English I'm taking that as a metaphor: speaking properly is a matter of finesse. It just sounds nicer that way.

Comment: (a) They're all grammatical. (b) '2' sounds the most natural. (c) The 'do' support _can_ give a pragmatic enhancement (conveying sincerity, as you suggest), but would often sound over-effusive. Mark Sloane could carry it. Bart Simpson, no. (d) If one is going to use '1' or '3', I'd say '1' sounds rather dated and formal, working against the sincerity marking: I'd stick with '3'.

Comment: Thanks Edwin, feel free to post this as an answer (ideally with a reference, if you can find one).